# Customer must register when open site in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, user-registration

I have problem in registration area when my site is opened by any customer he must register in my site than after he can access the site.

Is there any option in prestashop .. ?

Thanks,

Bhavik M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want people to be able to purchase without registering?

`Enable guest checkout` under `Back Office -> Preferences` allows people to purchase without needing to register.

Comment: Nope I want all the user who visit my site should be register first than after he can view or purchase items.
Because whoever visits should be registered on our site for future ref. and schemes / mass mailings etc..

Comment: So you want users to register before they can even view your site?  Sorry I dont understand what your asking.

Comment: Yes exactly I want like this. all users must registered before they can perchase or view the site.

Comment: I think there is a module for this called `Private Shop` [here](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/43991-module-private-shop-hide-your-shop-or-prices-from-non-registered-users-entire-shop-or-parts/).  Never used it though and its not free.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me ... Is there another way to collect the email id..?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - open another question.

Comment: Ok No Problem We have buy module.

Answer (score 0):

As @didster told you, PrestaShop has the "Guest checkout" feature, that allows your customer to purchase products, without having to create an account on your shop.